# Error while upgrading to 10.10

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I tried to upgrade 10.04 to 10.10 and got an error: 'E:Couldn't configure pre-depend x11-common for x11-xkb-utils, probably a dependency cycle.'. Can I fix this and finalize the upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead reinstall your system files by running the 10.10 installer as normal, and when it comes to partitioning, mount your partitions as normal, **BUT DO NOT FORMAT**.

This will overwrite the system files from 10.04 and replace with with those from 10.10, although it will also remove any third part applications you have installed, as well as resetting all your customised settings to their default values. The only part of your OS that will remain intact will be the contents of your home directory.

Comment: Tempting but I'm going to wait for a solution. Maybe I'll try dpkg --force-depends --remove x11-xkb-utils.

Comment: And my Home folder would not be a problem in case of a fresh install because I have a partition just for it.

Comment: I found no answer for this bug and I did a pseudo-fresh install. I kept the home folder/partition and formated the other

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this command:

```
dpkg --force-depends --remove x11-xkb-utils
```

It came from comment number 5 of [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x11-xkb-utils/+bug/639933) bug report.

Comment: I tried to remove the package in Synaptic but it gave me a really big list of other packages, some I would say are important, that it had to remove as well.

Comment: I finally tried this command but after that I got the same error.